# How to keep my requests ordered when preflight OPTIONS requests are sent beforehand?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, cors, preflight

I'm sending two requests:

```
let gameId = 'myGameId';
let chatRoomId = 'myChatRoomId';
requester.sendRequest(
   'POST', '/createGame', {gameId: gameId});
requester.sendRequest(
   'POST', '/createChatRoom', {gameId: gameId, chatRoomId: chatRoomId});
```

And as far as I know, those should get to the server in the same order I just sent them, because that's a guarantee of TCP.

However, when I send these out, it sometimes reaches the server out of order. When I inspect Chrome's console, I see that there is a preflight OPTIONS request sent out (always in the correct order) but then the server might respond to them out of order (it's a google app engine server), or they might arrive out of order.

Chrome waits for the OPTIONS response to come back before it sends out the real POST request, which means my POST requests are out of order.

The only solution I can see is to put .then()s on the requests, which is unacceptable because waiting for every dependent request would slow down my application too much.

Any ideas for how I can get around this frustrating preflight request, or order my requests somehow?

Comment: That's strange, but you should handle `OPTIONS` request on the server level (apache / nginx). Just return a 204 status code for every OPTIONS request.

Comment: I'm using App Engine, and it's already returning 200 for every OPTIONS request it sees. On top of that, this is a locally run app engine dev server, which means it's not hitting different machines or anything, which could have explained the out of order requests. Truly odd. I wish there was a way to tell Chrome to preserve the order of the things I send out.